# Is R dbplyr "smart" enough to determine the SQL database type and apply appropriate syntax?

Tags: sql, r, dbplyr

```
library(tidyverse)
con <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")
copy_to(con, mtcars)
mtcars2 <- tbl(con, "mtcars")
```

As I'm starting to learn SQL my first big lesson is that the syntax will be different dependent on database type.

For example, this type of query will often work:

```
mtcars3 <- DBI::dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT * FROM mtcars LIMIT 5")
```

But on some SQL databases I try `SELECT * FROM xyz LIMIT 5` and I get a syntax error. I then try something along the lines of:

```
DBI::dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT TOP 5 * FROM xyz")
```

and I'm able to get the result I want.

**This makes me very curious** as to what will happen when I start using dbplyr exclusively and forego using SQL queries at all (to the extent possible). Is dbplyr going to be "smart" enough to recognize the different SQL databases I'm working in? And more importantly will dbplyr apply the correct syntax, dependent on database type?

Comment: I tested against SQL Server (`select top 5 ...`) and SQLite (`select ... limit 5`) and it was correct, so there is server dialect in there. Quickly looking at [the source code](https://github.com/tidyverse/dbplyr/tree/master/R) reveals it appears to support (at least in part): Access, Hive, Impala, SQL Server, MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQLite, and Teradata. I wonder if the rest of your curiosity is more a question for the developers, as their intent is key to its applicability.

Comment: @r2evans At this point in time my dplyr skills are pretty good, but SQL experience is close to nil. So I don't even know what type of SQL database I'm working in half the time. I'll just throw queries at whatever SQL database I'm in until one works, steamrolling over the syntax errors. For now, if I can just stick to dbplyr and not have to worry about all this I'll be happy. I hope that's the intent of the developers, I imagine so based on my understanding of the tidyverse.

Comment: It is ... but realize that not all `dplyr` verbs are instantly translatable into SQL-speak, so be careful. When in doubt, I suggest you include `head` in your tests to make sure you have non-SQL verbs after all effective filtering/slicing, otherwise you may accidentally "collect" too much (all) data from the table(s).

Comment: @r2evans I will do that. Great tip.

Comment: I think that translates into: `filter` and `select` as early as possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, `dbplyr` is 'smart' enough to use the connect type of the table when translating `dplyr` commands to database (SQL) syntax. Consider the following example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(dbplyr)
data(mtcars)

# mimic postgre database
df_postgre = tbl_lazy(mtcars, con = simulate_postgres())
df_postgre %>% head(5) %>% show_query()

# resulting SQL translation
<SQL>
SELECT *
FROM `df`
LIMIT 5

# mimic MS server database
df_server = tbl_lazy(mtcars, con = simulate_mssql())
df_server %>% head(5) %>% show_query()

# resulting SQL translation
<SQL>
SELECT TOP(5) *
FROM `df`
```

You can experiment with the different `simulate_*` functions in `dbplyr` to check translations for your particular database.